# Why does my QQuick application crash on Ubuntu?

Tags: qt, c++, qml, crash

Basically I have (The Game class just wraps QGuiApplication):

```
int Game::run()
{
    QQuickView * mMainView = new QQuickView;
    mMainView->setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    mMainView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:///main.qml"));

    mMainView->show();

    return mApp.exec();
}
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Game game(argc, argv);
    return game.run();
}
```

And the QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Rectangle {
    width: 256
    height: 256
}
```

When I compile and run, it crashes like this:

```
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
#1  0x00007ffff6858221 in QCoreApplication::arguments() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5
#2  0x00007fffed9f9ad3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#3  0x00007fffed9f9fbd in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#4  0x00007fffeda06af2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#5  0x00007fffed9f9731 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
#6  0x00007ffff6fb4efe in QWindow::create() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#7  0x00007ffff6fb57b0 in QWindow::setVisible(bool) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5
#8  0x000000000041f04c in Game::run (this=this@entry=0x7fffffffd9b0) at /home/xxxxxx/src/game.cpp:71
#9  0x000000000041e44a in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdc78) at /home/xxxxxx/main.cpp:11
```

WTF? I cannot run even a simplest possible QQuick application..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the signature of `QGuiApplication`'s constructor is actually `QGuiApplication(int & argc, char ** argv)`.

Notice that **reference `&`** with `argc` ! :)

I had passed `argc` by value so the app crashed when `argc` variable went out of scope.

Comment: thank you so much, I was searching for this for 6 hours!